# How to Stop Node.js on Ubuntu and log out without stopping

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I just put my node application up on my ubuntu server.  I successfully started the program using

```
nodejs index.js
```

Now it gives me the "listening on *:3000"

The problem is that I am ssh'd into my ubuntu server, but the cursor is stuck under the "listening" line.

1) How can I close my ssh session and leave the node running?  Should I have started the node with a different user?

2) Once I successfully close my ssh session and the node is still running.  How can I stop node once I ssh back into the server?

3) Say I ssh into the server and start run my nodejs file, but I then want to do some other simple work for unrelated sites on the same server.  Since the cursor is stuck after "listening" line, how can I go about doing anything else?

Comment: This is what you'll want to use: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen Alternatively, you can run your command as a service. Look into UpStart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) program. Screen is a terminal multiplexer, which allows a user to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal window or remote terminal session (such as when using SSH).

It can be started by typing `screen` on a terminal. Inside it, you can call node.js as usual. Then you press `Ctrl+a` and type `d` to detach it. To re-attach a detached session type `screen -r`.

More information can be found on the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/)